# Should I ask and answer a question that isn't on SO?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Last night, I spent 2 hours trying to figure out how to do something. I couldn't find anything on StackOverflow that answered my question, and Google was totally unhelpful, even though it involved how to get 2 very popular services working together in the most basic of ways.

Is it acceptable to ask a question on StackOverflow solely for the purpose of answering it myself, so as to help build it up as knowledge base, rather than for the sole purpose of solving my individual problems?

Comment: Definitely yes! It's great that you want to spend that time.

Comment: very good question, i'd hope the answer would be yes but i can't help there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! It seems the answer is yes; Here's the result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441661/how-do-i-integrate-a-simple-unsigned-google-checkout-cart-with-google-analytics/